# discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler returning multiple records for same user?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

When I invoke `discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler:` the returned array of `CKDiscoveredUserInfo` has three distinct `userRecordIDs` but these are all for a person with the same firstName + lastName.  The three `userRecordIDs` share the same `recordName` but differ by `zoneID`.  As best I can figure this is the same person with three 'iCloud' email addresses: icloud.com, me.com, mac.com.  Presenting all three in my App's UI is a non-starter given that they are indistinguishable.

Is there any reason to choose one of the multiple records over another?  Is my presumption that they are indeed different iCloud mail addresses correct?  Can I go from userRecordID to email?

[I know the email accounts; presumably I could query with `discoverUserInfoWithEmailAddress:completionHandler` and correlate the results myself.

Answer (score 0):

The `recordName` is the only part that really matters here, but it's odd that the `userRecordIDs` have different `zoneIDs`. They should all be in the default public zone, so you might be hitting a bug. What zone IDs are you seeing?

If you have to pick one record ID, go with the one in `-[CKRecordZone defaultRecordZone]`